# Load large UIImages asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I have an NSManagedObject which has pictures that are stored somewhere like `/var/mobile/Applications/.../.../uniqueIDforNSMO/Pictures/`

I have no problem getting these pictures off the disk by finding them based on the NSMO's uniqueID, I have a DataController that will pull them for me, and that is very performant. But I run into issues when I try to add these pictures to a view, the UI becomes blocked. I suspect the problem is that these images are very high resolution (they are images from the iPad camera roll).

Displaying 5 images takes about 3 seconds, leaving the UI blocked. Displaying even just 2 images blocks the damn UI. Here's how I add them, on a background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [self.photos objectAtIndex:index];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    });
});
```

If I set the imageView.image without dispatching it takes even longer.

Could the problem be that the images are so large, while the cell's imageViews are only 150x150? Or is it because I only have a reference to the image at first, so the realization of the image is the slow part?

Can anyone suggest anything here? I have tried resizing the images before they are returned in the array and that did not help.

Comment: Have you tried storing a resized 150x150 thumbnail on the disk and loading that instead of the whole image and scaling it down?

Comment: I will eventually need the full resolution image because they will be able to tap the cell to view the full, but I think you have a good point, I could store both but only display the full resolution image on demand.

Comment: No benefit of running - objectAtIndex: in the global queue. If you suspect the size of image files, where these files are loaded into self.photos (NSArray I guess?) would take a while: I/O + JPEG decoding. Is that done in cellForRowAtIndexPath: too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the images are being lazily loaded - `UIImage` only loads the image into memory when it needs to be drawn. What you can do is eagerly load the image on a background thread:

1. Create a `CGBitmapContextRef` using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`
2. Draw the image into the context
3. Get a new image from the context using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`
4. Pass the image back to the main thread

Answer (score 0):

As they are high-resolution images, I would suggest that you should make persistent thumbnails cache for that. Generating thumbnail real-time every time would waste too much CPU time unnecessarily.